# Ionic 3 ion-option listen to uncheck/unselect event?

Tags: ionic3

Using Ionic 3.9.2 `ionSelect` event is only fired when i select, but how do i listen when unselect ? `ionChange` event is fired only when i close the modal clicking on `OK` button, `click` does not fire

```
  <ion-select [selectOptions]="{cssClass: 'add-video-to-playlist'}" [hidden]=true multiple="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedPlaylistIds" (ionChange)="playListsSelected()" #playListSelect>
<ion-option *ngFor="let playlist of playlists" [value]="playlist.playlist_Id" (ionSelect)="some()">{{playlist.playlist_Id}} - {{playlist.name}}</ion-option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was trying to write some custom directive to extend the behavior of current `<ion-option>` directive but i was unsuccessful. Click events are prevented by tap-click.js

So, i end up hacking source code [ionic-v3/blob](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-v3/blob/20dfbdd3037fa86dcda2a5ce07a2476ae344a9ee/src/components/select/select.ts#L373)

changing the handler to

```
handler: function (selectedOption) {
  input.ionSelect.emit({ 'value': input.value, 'checked': selectedOption.checked});
}
```

it works, i have no idea why by default event is emitted only when checked, i hope it won't bite me in some special circumstances

i have interface forced to `alert`